# many producers and one consumer polling all messages at once

Tags: java, multithreading, message-queue

I have a webapp that for every request stores some information (e.g. client ip address) in some collection. From time to time I need to empty it, serialize all elements to xml and send the xml to other web service. I could create and send one xml for every request but I'd rather send the data in chunks (not to communicate too often with the webservice). I have no requirements regarding the max size of the collection (except for no outofmemoryerror), a period when a file must be sent and a min/max file size. It's also acceptable that sometimes jvm crashes and we lose all the data stored in the memory.

I understand that many threads (servlet container generated threads) will add elements to the collection and once in a while one consumer thread will fetch all elements from the collection, serialize them to xml and send a file. Could you recommend the design?

Should I use a busy-wait in a consumer thread? 
Which thread (producer or consumer) should check whether collection size is some max/threshold size? 
Can I use synchronize on the collection and notifyAll on producer side to notify a consumer?
Should I use synchronize and while(size < MAX) { wait() } on consumer side?
Will drainTo be better than  List temp = new ArrayList<>(collection); ?

This is my first thought. I'm sure there are plenty of reasons to criticize it:

```
public void add(Info info){
    synchronized (collection) {
        collection.add(info);
        if (collection.size() > THRESHOLD) {
             collection.notify();
        }
    }
}

public void send(){
    while (true) {
        List<Info> temp = null;
        synchronized (collection) {
            try {
                collection.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            List<Info> temp = new ArrayList<>(collection);
            collection.clear();
        }
        serializeAndSend(temp);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling your own, at least consider using something like [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or something else from [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

As-is, your current code will not work, as your `notify()` and `wait()` calls are not working against the same object.

Your requirements are interesting.  What if the JVM dies (for any reason), and you loose all the queued data, for example?  Anyway, following your comment - you could still do something similar to what you had before - filter all add operations through a custom method, and if the collection reaches a certain size, then `serializeAndSend`.  However, if you follow this approach, then you really don't need a collection with concurrency support.  I also see that you updated your code to call `collection.wait()`, which is good.

Comment: Thanks, but would LinkedBlockingQueue change anything in this case (take/drainTo should be called only when a certain threshold size is expected)?

Comment: @user1051075 - Please see the update to my answer.  (Put there instead of a comment, given a length.)